# Django Queryset Iterator for Ordered queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to use queryset iterator for iterating over a large dataset. Django provides `iterator()` for this, but that will hit database for each iteration. I found following code for iteration in chunks -

```
  def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunksize=1000):
    '''''
    Iterate over a Django Queryset ordered by the primary key
    This method loads a maximum of chunksize (default: 1000) rows in it's
    memory at the same time while django normally would load all rows in it's
    memory. Using the iterator() method only causes it to not preload all the
    classes.
    Note that the implementation of the iterator
    does not support ordered query sets.
    '''
    pk = 0
    last_pk = queryset.order_by('-pk').values_list('pk', flat=True).first()
    if last_pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.order_by('pk')
        while pk < last_pk:
            for row in queryset.filter(pk__gt=pk)[:chunksize]:
                pk = row.pk
                yield row
            gc.collect()
```

This works for unordered queryset. Is there any solution/workaround to do this on an ordered queryset?

Comment: I think you should accept the Igor's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is mine, with sort function.

By the way the iterator you are using has a "forever loop" when in process the queryset items are modified: deleted or added, even one item.

And below iterator has no useless query on last_pk

```
def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunksize=10000, key=None):
    key = [key] if isinstance(key, str) else (key or ['pk'])
    counter = 0
    count = chunksize
    while count == chunksize:
        offset = counter - counter % chunksize
        count = 0
        for item in queryset.all().order_by(*key)[offset:offset + chunksize]:
            count += 1
            yield item
        counter += count
        gc.collect()
```

Comment: Good catch with infinite loop and nice solution. Very useful!

Comment: This will not work when using `bulk_create` for child models. For example, if you are iterating using this approach, and within an iteration, you execute `bulk_create` for a model that is a child to that of the iterable. As a consequence, trying to limit and offset in the second iteration will result in an empty queryset.